# Whats the solution of this problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $R_1 = \{(x, y): |x - y| ≤ 1\}$ and $R_2 = \{(x, y): 2x + y ≤ 6\}$ be relations on the set $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$.
List the elements of $R_1$ and $R_2$.

Comment: What is your issue? You have straightforward rules that relate a pair $(x,y)$.  Just find all of the pairs for which each of these relations are satisfied

Comment: Since you are new to this site . Piece of advise . Dont directly ask the question expecting for an answer . Show what you have done till now . In specific where are you facing the problem

Answer (score 0):

$R_1=\{ (1,2),(2,1),(3,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,3)\} $ and $R_2=\{(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,1),(2,2)\}$

Answer (score 0):

A relation set defines pairs of elements that are *related* (whatever that means in the context).

So for $R_1$, you are asked to find pairs of elements $(x,y)$ st $ |x -y| \leq 1$ ie, pairs that are at most 1 apart. So you just go through your set A and pick every pair that matches the constraint.

Hopefully that helps you understand.